# Where to read docs for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis?

Tags: c#, roslyn, visual-studio-sdk, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015 (after installing the [SDK preview](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx)), I created a 'diagnostic with code fix' project. The skeleton code is full of interesting types such as `DiagnosticAnalyzer` (under Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics) and `CodeFixProvider` (under Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeFixes).

Where can I read the docs for these types? I couldn't find them on msdn. All I found was a *different* namespace with a *confusingly similar name* [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .

Ideally msdn would have a full guide to writing a DiagnosticAnalyzer, as well as the usual reference documentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are all Roslyn related, so the best place to look is the [Roslyn documentation](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/documentation)

It has [samples, walkthroughs](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Samples-and-Walkthroughs), [FAQ](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/FAQ), etc. Specifically here's a PDF file showing [How To: Write a C# Diagnostic and Code Fix](https://www.codeplex.com/Download?ProjectName=roslyn&DownloadId=822458) using a `DiagnosticAnalyzer`.

MSDN doesn't usually have information on technologies still in preview. I can only guess that until VS 2015 ships all the MSDN articles would be published (but we'll have to wait and see).

Comment: Brilliant thanks. It looks like the API has changed a little since April but that guide should be really helpful. When this is released properly I expect people are going to make a lot of cool stuff.

Comment: Wicked I've got my DiagnosticAnalyzer working without yet a CodeFixProvider. I really like the API.

Answer (score 1):

Roslyn is now moved to https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

I think still the documentation is not that very great...!

my personal openion

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question, but the docs have moved
[Roslyn Wiki](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/wiki)
[A useful example: build a c# analyzer](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix.md)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31628761)